# "Expressions" option is not availble for Flat File Connection Mangaer propery

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm loading a multiple Flat files by adding looping. But i'm not able to see the Expressions option in Property pane for Flat source connection manger in SQL Server data tools.

But i'm able to see the expressions options available for "Foreach loop container" propery although i couldn't see ConnectionString  is also not available for Property column at "Property Expressions Editor" window.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Connection Managers only allow you to use expressions from their Properties menu. Control flow objects, like a `Foreach Loop Container` expose their Expressions from the object themselves (as well as through their properties menu).

Right click on your Flat File Connection Manager and select Properties (Alt+Enter) In the ensuing menu, you should have the Expressions collection exposed. And you can see that I set the `ConnectionString` property to @[User::CurrentFileName]. I also click the A->Z to sort my properties alphabetically vs the default grouping of "Categorized," so your menu might have things in a different order.

[image]

In your screen shot, you have focus on your `Data Flow Task` which is inside your `Foreach Loop Container`. I can tell this is so because the righthand, docked window shows "EngineThreads: 10" which is a Data Flow setting. Also, the pop up window has properties that are only available in a Data Flow. You need to click on the  `File Source Data` at the bottom of your package and *then* select properties.

Comment: i followed exactly as mentioned above before i posting the question and after looking at your answer, i can get to Expressions by property pane of either Foreach loop container or the "Data Flow Task" but none no there's Property Expression editor contains "ConnectionString"

Comment: In your screen shot, you have focus on your `Data Flow Task` which is inside your `Foreach Loop Container`. I can tell this is so because the righthand, docked window shows "EngineThreads: 10" which is a Data Flow setting. Also, the pop up window has properties that are only available in a Data Flow. You need to click on the  `File Source Data` at the bottom of your package and *then* select properties.

Comment: I stumbled over the same problem, it does not seem very intuitive and it is also easy to overlook the very small "ConnetionManagers" pane when the Connection Managers are also displayed on the right side... thx!

Answer (score 0):

From Solution Explorer, I had only *File Name* and *Full Path* for properties on my Flat File Source (VS 2013).  But if I opened the same connection's properties on the *Package Explorer* Tab, *Expressions* **is** in the *Properties* pane.  The data source in the *Connection Managers* pane (below the designer pane on *Control Flow* or *Data Flow* tabs) gives the additional properties too as indicated previously.

ALM